# how to share user preferences between projects with multiproject trac?

Tags: trac

I've a multiproject trac setup that works perfectly for any single project, intertrac links are fine too. My only problem is that my users have to provide their preferences for every project. Is there an easy way to get around this and have user preferences shared among projects?

thanks, Viktor

Comment: That would be a nice feature request. It would require something along the lines of defining one Trac instance as the "master", and have the others get their session data from that instance's database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the  [TracUserSyncPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracUserSyncPlugin) that promise just that. Currently it's marked "beta" and "unfinished", so you may want to join in for more development, but at least you'll have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There's not an easy way to do this that I know of.  However, user preference data is stored in the database so it should be possible to write a script that synchronizes the preference data between the different databases.